# Comparing a list of results to a list of strings and putting them in a category

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app that tells users what ingredients are in their food that they want to avoid. 
What they want to avoid is a list called `LookingForThings` 
The matching results from the api are called `passedResult`
As an example: `LookingForThings: [Added Sugar, Dairy, Non Vegan]` 
`PassedResult: [corn syrup, lactose, syrup, milk, butter, skim milk, milkfat]`

I want to display this data to the page with it's correlating category. Such as:

##### Added Sugar

corn syrup, syrup

And the rest of the categories with all of their matches too. 
So far I am using this code:

```
  Map<String, List<String>> categorizeResults(List<String> passedResults) {
    Map<String, List<String>> categorizedResults = {};

    // Iterate over the collection of maps
    for (var entry in keywordLists) {
      var keyword = entry.keys.first;
      var list = entry.values.first;

      // Find elements in passedResults that match the list associated with the keyword
      List<String> matchingElements =
          passedResults.where((element) => list.contains(element)).toList();

      // Add matching elements to categorizedResults under the keyword
      if (matchingElements.isNotEmpty) {
        categorizedResults[keyword] = matchingElements;
      }
    }
    print(categorizedResults);
    return categorizedResults;
}
```

However at the moment this is stopping on the first result. So I am getting a `categorizedResults` list that is: `{added sugar: [corn syrup]}`
How can I get this to categorize all of the results?

Comment: I think the issue lies in the `.first` variable initializations. What type is `keywordLists`?

Comment: I think you are right with the .first, I'm going to experiment. 
The keywordLists looks like this `[{seed oils: [sunflower oil, sunflower lecithin, sesame oil,]}` with all of the different categories

Comment: You probably want something like `for (var entry in keywordMap.entries)` and use `entry.key` and `entry.value`

Comment: What do you mean by keywordList.entries? Should that be created as a local variable?

Comment: I am assuming that `keywordLists` can be a map with the keyword as the key and the list of bad ingredients as the value. But I am still unsure why `keywordList` is a list and not a map. What is the type and an example value would be helpful

Comment: The type is `List<Map<String, List<String>>>` 
Here's a very trimmed example of the keywordLists
`({seed oils: [sunflower oil, sunflower lecithin, sesame oil,vegetable oil, canola oil]})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm should iterate through each passedResult and check against every category in keywordLists to find if it belongs to one or more categories.

You can paste it in dartpad to check if it works as you expect:

```
void main() {
  Map<String, List<String>> keywordLists = {
    'Added Sugar': ['corn syrup', 'syrup'],
    'Dairy': ['lactose', 'milk', 'butter', 'skim milk', 'milkfat'],
    'Non Vegan': ['milk', 'butter'],
  };

  List<String> passedResults = [
    'corn syrup',
    'lactose',
    'syrup',
    'milk',
    'butter',
    'skim milk',
    'milkfat'
  ];

  Map<String, List<String>> categorizedResults =
      categorizeResults(passedResults, keywordLists);

  print(categorizedResults);
}

Map<String, List<String>> categorizeResults(
    List<String> passedResults, Map<String, List<String>> keywordLists) {
  Map<String, List<String>> categorizedResults = {};

  keywordLists.forEach((key, value) {
    categorizedResults[key] = [];
  });

  for (String result in passedResults) {
    keywordLists.forEach((keyword, list) {
      if (list.any(
          (element) => result.toLowerCase().contains(element.toLowerCase()))) {
        categorizedResults[keyword]?.add(result);
      }
    });
  }

  return categorizedResults;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to implement this solution into my code but I am getting `The argument type 'List<Map<String, List<String>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, List<String>>'. ` error. I tried adding the suggested typecast but it errors out when the function runs. 
Here is the type of my keyword list, I'm not sure what I am missing `List<Map<String, List<String>>> keywordLists = [
  {"seed oils": seedOils},
  {"banned In EU": bannedInEU}
];`

Comment: Map<String, List<String>> categorizeResults(
    List<String> passedResults, List<Map<String, List<String>>> keywordLists) {
  Map<String, List<String>> categorizedResults = {};

  keywordLists.forEach((map) {
    map.forEach((key, _) => categorizedResults[key] = []);
  });

  for (String result in passedResults) {
    keywordLists.forEach((keywordMap) {
      keywordMap.forEach((keyword, list) {
        if (list.any((element) => result.toLowerCase().contains(element.toLowerCase()))) {
          categorizedResults[keyword]?.add(result);
        }
      });
    });
  }

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as expected.